# Why does using node.js in heroku give me different results when the code is working in local?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have uploaded all my code to Heroku. However, I get advised to look on the Heroku log details and receive this message in my terminal.

```
2019-02-12T13:23:48.102698+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=frozen- 
wildwood-17884.herokuapp.com request_id=55cdcdac-a94a-49f3-a050- 
920bad07f674 fwd="134.19.180.166" dyno= connect= service= status=503 
bytes= protocol=https
```

I have also researched on other pages and attempted to add below to the bottom of my server.js file but no luck.

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", 
this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

Any advice on the issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');
const app = express()

const apiKey = '****************';

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {weather: null, error: null});
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  let city = req.body.city;
  let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${apiKey}`

request(url, function (err, response, body) {
  if(err){
  res.render('index', {weather: null, error: 'Error, please try 
again'});
} else {
  let weather = JSON.parse(body)
  if(weather.main == undefined){
    res.render('index', {weather: null, error: 'Error, please try again'});
  } else {
    let weatherText = `It's ${weather.main.temp} degrees in ${weather.name}!`;
    res.render('index', {weather: weatherText, error: null});
     }
   }
 });
```

})

The results show in an error page on the heroku app. However, the app is running perfectly within local.

Comment: For the records, I also have below added at the bottom of the server.js file.

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your last comment and in the case that `process.env.PORT` is not defined, it appears that you are attempting to run two listeners on the same TCP port. This cannot work as a listener will open the port for read, causing all other attempts to open the port to fail.